# ios: inapp purchase content stops downloading from Apple server after 95 percent download

Tags: ios, ios6, download, in-app-purchase

I am using IAP in my app and hosting content on apple server. After purchase of product, downloading starts normally. I am tracking downloading through progress bar. But when download reaches 95 percent transaction gets removed and it doesn't get finish callback:

```
    2013-11-14 11:54:06.365 InAppPurchaseDemo[10365:60b] progress ::0.950000  
    2013-11-14 11:54:07.826 InAppPurchaseDemo[10365:60b] downloadContentIdentifier    com.mycompanyName.myapp.product1 
    2013-11-14 11:54:09.411 InAppPurchaseDemo[10365:60b] send Notification  
    2013-11-14 11:54:09.519 InAppPurchaseDemo[10365:60b] transaction removed
```

My application is live on app store and some of my users are facing this problem and on some user devices it is working fine.
I am testing IAP on device FYI.

I don't know what part of code I should post for this so not posted it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not actually finished? When I output the progress of my hosted content download it also doesn't go past 95%. However, it does finish and I get notified that is complete.
Are you perhaps testing it in the simulator? It doesn't work there. You must use a real device.

Comment: I am using using real device it self. On one device it reaches to 95 percent and stops while on another device it is fully downloaded any unzipping me the content.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me.I am still having the same issue.